# SSIS Package with file throught an ActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file, ssis

I'm working with ASP.NET MVC 4 and Entity Framework. I've created a SSIS package which extracts data from an Excel file and stores it into a table in my database.

What I want to do is to use my SSIS package with an uploaded Excel file (into an `ActionResult`) to store the data.

Here I have a sample of code which returns me "Success". So the package is correctly executed:

```
Console.WriteLine("Loading SSIS Service...");
//Application object allows load your SSIS package
Application app = new Application();
//In order to retrieve the status (success or failure) after running SSIS Package
DTSExecResult result;
//Specify the location of SSIS package - dtsx file
string SSISPackagePath = @"C:\Package.dtsx";
//Load your package
Package pckg = (Package)app.LoadPackage(SSISPackagePath, null);
//Execute the package and retrieve result
result = pckg.Execute();
//Print the status success or failure of your package
Console.WriteLine("{0}", result.ToString());

Console.ReadLine();
```

Any idea about how to couple this with an uploaded file?

EDIT: Okay the package works fine, I just need to modify the source file. Any idea?

EDIT (2): After that the problem has been solved for the Excel file case, I wanted to know if it is possible to do the same thing for a **flat file** by doing this:

```
pckg.Connections["NameOfTheConnectionManager"].ConnectionString = @"C:\Test-CSV.csv";


result = pckg.Execute();
```

Comment: It would be best to ask a new question regarding your second edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly (need to dynamically set the excel file name at runtime) then you'd just need to edit your connection string before executing. Code approximate

```
//Load your package
Package pckg = (Package)app.LoadPackage(SSISPackagePath, null);
// This needs to correspond to the CM's name in the package
// and the properties of the current CM's ConnectionString
pckg.Connections["Excel Connection Manager"].ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\folder\fileName.xls;Extended Properties=""EXCEL 8.0;HDR=YES"";";
//Execute the package and retrieve result
result = pckg.Execute();
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped me ! However, I have an other question : how can I do the same thing for a flat file? Assuming there is no "Excel Connection Manager" for such file, I have no idea about how to proceed...

Comment: Assume the Connection Manager for the flat file does not exist (and therefore needs to be created) or are you saying the CM for the flat file exists and you need to do the same dynamic location logic applied?

Comment: Second case : CM exists and I need to do the same dynamic location logic.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have create the console application to run your package. You can do the following.

**SSIS:**

1. Open your SSIS package
2. Create a package level variable called Excel "FilePath". For now,
   Have some sample file location.
3. Click on the Excel connection manager. Go to properties and go to
   expression and configure it as shown in the screenshot.

[image]

**Console project:**

Open your console project and try the following code. You should path file path from the string arg[].

```
Console.WriteLine("Loading SSIS Service...");
//Get the file path
string filePath = args[0];
//Application object allows load your SSIS package
Application app = new Application();
//In order to retrieve the status (success or failure) after running SSIS Package
DTSExecResult result;
//Specify the location of SSIS package - dtsx file
string SSISPackagePath = @"C:\Package.dtsx";
//Load your package
Package pckg = (Package)app.LoadPackage(SSISPackagePath, null);
//Assign the source file path. File path from the argument[0].
pkg.Variables["FilePath"].Value = filePath;
//Execute the package and retrieve result
result = pckg.Execute();
//Print the status success or failure of your package
Console.WriteLine("{0}", result.ToString());
Console.ReadLine();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think your answer will become helpful with my second case... Another package, same concept but instead of using an Excel File as the source File, I'm using a flat file (in fact, a CSV file). Will the variable trick work for this?

Comment: same solution will work for CSV file as well. In the expression, you should use the connection string property instead of ExcelFilePath.